# Connecting to a database without remote connection

Tags: mysql, database, security, phpmyadmin

Due to security considerations from my provider, I am not able to MySQL Workbench to connect to my database. The only way to access my database is to use phpmyadmin. Because I'm used to use MySQL Workbench and their tools, it is for me much easier to maintain my database. Using phpmyadmin is annoying, so I'm googeling a solution to use anyway MySQL Workbench. Is there a way to break this security consideration or to connect MySQL Workbench through phpmyadmin to gain access to the database?

Comment: Nope. It's a security measure. It would be theoretically possible to build a local client that uses PHP scripts on the server to pass data through, but I've never seen anything like this implemented

Comment: What sort of hosting is it? Do you get a shell? If so, you could SSH-tunnel the MySQL server port (conventionally 3306) to your local desktop and run Workbench against that.

Comment: you can allow your ip from cpanel. it may works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hosting provided did it recently then I am pretty sure it is must be a response to this terrible [security flaw](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2012/06/11/cve-2012-2122-a-tragically-comedic-security-flaw-in-mysql) discovered in mysql last month. The attack is as simple as running that one line shell command.

Not all OS/MySQL combinations are vulnerable. In case your hosting company was, then for a few moments - all customers 
logins were at stake (including the root login).

To answer your question, unfortunately you can not do much in this case. You **cannot** do any port forwarding tricks even if you have shell(ssh) access because **normally** port forwarding isn't allowed in shared hosting environments.
In case you want to try, you can run this command on a unix box

```
$ ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 username@yoursite.com
```

If you can login and don't see any errors related to port forwarding, perhaps your can direct your workbench to **localhost** on port **3306** and theoretically it should work.

If you are using windows you can use putty to do port forwarding [as described here](http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think no. Only changing table Users in MySQL you can access from other IPs and hosts. And this table is not accessible by other users.